# How to retrieve key if passed in value is a json object?

Tags: javascript, dojo

```
var json={"america":"1234","india:"5678","britain":"789"}
```

This is a sample json object (there are thousands of key-value pairs in the actual json object). How do I retrieve the key from this object if I pass the value json["1234"]? The expected result is that I should be able to retrieve the key "america".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var json = {"america":"1234","india":"5678","britain":"789"};

function getValueByKey(obj, val) {
  // Looping on object keys
  return Object.keys(obj).filter(function (key) {
    return obj[key] === val
  })[0];
}

// For testing
console.log(getValueByKey(json, "1234")); // america

console.log(getValueByKey(json, "5678")); // india
```